# describe RDS cloudwatch alarms which are attached on RDS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to get alarms attached on RDS instances. But not able to get alarms names of RDS using below AWS CLI command.

```
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms-for-metric --namespace AWS/RDS --metric-name CPUUtilization --Dimensions Name=DBInstanceIdentifier,Value=My-DB
```

Getting output:

---

|DescribeAlarmsForMetric|
+-----------------------+

---

As same aws cli command i am trying to get alarms which are configured on EC2 Instance and its working for me

```
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms-for-metric --region $region --metric-name StatusCheckFailed --namespace AWS/EC2 --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=$i --output text --query 'MetricAlarms[].[AlarmName]'
```

Answer (score 1):

To reproduce the situation, I did the following:

- Launched an Amazon RDS for MySQL database instance
- Created an Amazon CloudWatch alarm on the database CPU Utilization

I then ran the command:

```
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms-for-metric --namespace AWS/RDS --metric-name CPUUtilization --dimensions Name=DBInstanceIdentifier,Value=stack
```

The response was:

```
{
    "MetricAlarms": [
        {
            "EvaluationPeriods": 1, 
            "TreatMissingData": "missing", 
            "AlarmArn": "...", 
            "StateUpdatedTimestamp": "2019-02-13T01:21:52.988Z", 
            "AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp": "2019-02-13T01:21:52.421Z", 
            "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold", 
            "AlarmActions": [], 
            "Namespace": "AWS/RDS", 
            "AlarmDescription": "stack", 
            "StateReasonData": "...", 
            "Period": 300, 
            "StateValue": "ALARM", 
            "Threshold": 0.0, 
            "AlarmName": "stack-alarm", 
            "Dimensions": [
                {
                    "Name": "DBInstanceIdentifier", 
                    "Value": "stack"
                }
            ], 
            "Statistic": "Average", 
            "StateReason": "Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint [2.1557377049180277 (13/02/19 01:16:00)] was greater than or equal to the threshold (0.0).", 
            "InsufficientDataActions": [], 
            "OKActions": [], 
            "ActionsEnabled": true, 
            "MetricName": "CPUUtilization"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, it seems to work fine for me.